# Pass variable to view Django

Tags: django, view, python-requests

Im pretty new to django. I have created an website that outputs data from an API to an table in django.
I created an app called 'display_networks'. Inside the views.py of this app i have the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .services import get_networks

# Create your views here.
class GetNetworks(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'networks.html'
    
    #context == dict
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'networks' : get_networks(),
        }
        return context
```

As you can see i import an function called 'get_networks' from .services (services.py).
Inside services.py i have the following code:

```
import os
import requests
import json

# Headers
apikey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
headers = {'x-cisco-meraki-api-key': format(str(apikey)), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
# Headers

def get_networks():
    
    url = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/organizations/XXXXX/networks/'
    
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    networks = r.json()
    
    return networks
```

Inside my app i have created a templates folder with an index.html. Inside this index.html i have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Meraki Networks</title>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css"
          integrity="sha256-8B1OaG0zT7uYA572S2xOxWACq9NXYPQ+U5kHPV1bJN4="
          rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav aria-label="main navigation" class="navbar is-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div class="navbar-item">
            <img alt="Meraki" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Meraki_Logo_2016.svg/1920px-Meraki_Logo_2016.svg.png"
                 style="margin-right: 0.5em;" width="142" height="142">Networks
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<table class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Network Name</th>
        <th>Network ID</th>
        <th>Time zone</th>
        <th>Tags</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for network in networks %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ network.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ network.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ network.timeZone }}</td>
        <td>{{ network.tags }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This works good and i have the data i want to display.

What i want to do is add an extra column to my table with the header "Get device info" and with an button titled 'Get devices' as the table data.

What this button has to do is send the variable 'network.id' to an different function in my services.py.
I have created a new function inside my services.py with the following code:

```
def get_devices(net_id):
    
    url = 'https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/'+net_id+'/devices/'
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    devices = r.json()
    
    return devices
```

The variable "net_id" has to come from the button click and the button has to call this function and display the output the same as i have done for the networks.

Does anybody have an idea how i can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would this button load a new page or you want it on the same page?

Comment: New page if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question asks how to pass a variable to a view. The answer is:

1. Pass it **inside** the url.
2. Pass it as a GET or POST parameter in the request (can be done using forms etc.).
3. Pass it inside the request body.

To solve your problem we shall use the 1st option for  it's simplicity. First in your urlpatterns we shall make a pattern that will capture some arguments and these shall be passed to the view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Other patterns
    path('device/<str:network_id>/', views.GetDevices.as_view(), name='get_devices'),
    # Other patterns
]
```

The `<str:network_id>` here means that `network_id` would be passed as a keyword argument to the view. Check more details about the [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/).

Your view GetDevices would handle getting the devices:

```
from .services import get_devices

class GetDevices(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'devices.html'
    
    #context == dict
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'devices' : get_devices(kwargs['network_id']),
        }
        return context
```

Now in your template with the table for networks you would write the following to add an anchor tag with a link to this new page:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'get_devices' network.id %}">Get Devices</a></td>
```

You can style this anchor to look like a button using css / actually put a button tag inside it.

I am sure you know how to make templates so I would leave the task of making `'devices.html'` to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation! I have added:
"from display_networks.views import GetNetworks, GetDevices" to my url.py from my project.and in my views.py from my app i added: "from .services import get_networks, get_devices".
I followed the rest of your instruction and it works like a charm! Thank you so much!!!!